# Does the following series converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum \frac{x^2}{n^2}$ where $x \in [5,\infty)$ clearly we can't apply the Weierstrass M test because as $x \longrightarrow \infty$ we can't say that $\sum \frac{x^2}{n^2} \leq \sum \frac{1}{n^2}$  and so i don't what i can conclude about the series.Any suggestions

Comment: Suppose $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Pick an $n_0$ such that $\lVert f - \sum_{n=0}^N f_n\rVert_\infty \leqslant 1$ for all $N\geqslant n_0$. What follows about $f_n$ for $n\geqslant n_0$?

Comment: So you mean we can apply dini's theorem ?

Comment: No, Dini's theorem requires the domain to be compact. We don't have that here.

Comment: Yeah i got it , thanks @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{n^2}=x^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=x^2\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Maybe this is not what you ment?

Comment: This also shows that the convergence is not uniform on the whole domain and that it is uniform on bounded subsets of the domain.